# Rectified Voltage doesn't seem possible

Tags: rectifier, analysis

This is my first question on this forum. I recently bought a used guitar amplifier and have the schematic. It's been almost 30 years since I worked in electronics but I thought maybe I could handle the circuit analysis of the power supply.

This amp runs off a typical 120Vac, the secondary voltage of the power transformer is 132Vac and the schematic shows the rectified DC voltage as 319Vdc. I've checked the test points shown on the schematic and the measured voltages are fairly close. My question is how does this rectifier achieve the 319 Vdc?

[image]

Comment: Google "Full Wave Bridge Rectifier".  That's what this circuit is.

Comment: And while I'm at it, note the Urban Myth about tube amps being dangerous is no myth.  This thing will turn your straight hair curly and your curly hair straight if you get zapped.  Before poking around, make sure you are absolutely able to determine there is zero volts on those big caps.  Most tube amps will have a 'drain resistor' to give them a way to discharge when you turn the power off...  Your drain resistor is R31.  470k will take a long time (minutes) to drain those caps, and if it fails, they'll "never" drain.

Answer (score 4):

The voltages shown are measured relative to ground, and they are assuming an AC-coupled average-reading multimeter. It's a simple bridge rectifier. The 10nF capacitors are to reduce buzz in the audio from the diodes.

The AC voltage coming out of the transformer secondary (red-to-red wires) will be more like 240VAC RMS. Half appears at each side relative to ground (when your multimeter subtracts the DC component as they normally do).

Peak voltage from a bridge rectifier, of course, is \$\sqrt{2}\$ times the RMS voltage, and the filter capacitors mean that you will measure close to that (minus a bit due to the ripple under load and the diode drops).

Here is a simulation showing the two voltages AC1/AC2 relative to ground and the transformer output voltage (AC1-AC2) and the DC output voltage (relative to ground).

[image]

If you imagine an average line for AC1/AC2 in the middle between the two peaks and ignore that DC offset (as your meter will on an AC volts range unless it is not an ordinary multimeter) you can see that the total amplitude of each relative to ground is half of the transformer winding output voltage.

Comment: yes, when i checked the voltages at the test points my meter was grounded to the chassis.  in earlier revisions of this powers supply the 10nF caps were not used.  from what I've read, the diodes are slow and the caps are for voltage spikes during the AC cycles.

Comment: Right, when the diodes turn off after the reverse recovery time (probably in the microseconds) there's a spike that can be audible- 120x a second.

Answer (score 2):

The Test Point measurement is relative to ground. Here is a scope plot for reference.

The transformer outputs about 230 VAC. This has a peak of about 320 V. This is what you get after the rectifier.

Your meter in AC mode probably has a cap to block the DC. So you have 320 Vp-p, or 160 Vpeak, or 113 Vrms

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbYkoM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: my question is with the circuit analysis.  TP 22 shows 132 VAC with respect to ground. I measure 115.8VAC with a meter which is RMS.  115.8Vrms = 163.8 Vp    Vdc = 2Vp/PI.  using the formula, i have:   (2*163.8) / pi = 104 Vdc .  what am i missing in the calculation to get the 319Vdc.  even using the TP voltages of 132 Vac converted to RMS doesn't add up.  I came here to the experts for help.

Comment: BTW, I'll check into the simulation.  that's very interesting.

Comment: @StevenShelton - The equations you are using in your comments don't apply for the waveform at the TP.

Comment: given the 132VAC as the secondary voltage, how is the rectified voltage of 319 calculated?

Comment: Transformer secondary is about 230 VAC, which is about 319 Vpeak.

Comment: i just starting looking at this amp over the weekend.  I'll be back with the mathematical analysis to show how the rectified dc voltage is achieved.

Comment: @StevenShelton I think you are being mislead by the 132V AC secondary label on the diagram. It says this will measure 132V secondary AC relative to ground. The statement that the secondary is "about 230V AC" is relative to the other end of that transformer winding. I still can't make the numbers quite work but I think this explains a lot of the difference.